# Segue from selected uitableview to uiwebview

Tags: uiwebview, webview, uitableview, segue

I am using storyboards and the latest version of Xcode. I have seen some of the other related questions on this but nothing is specific enough for me. Perhaps best would be a tutorial if anyone knows of any!

So I am attempting to segue from my TableViewController to another viewcontroller (DetailViewController) that contains a UIWebView. I am using two NSMutableArrays. One that has the tableview title names, and the other which contains my local .html files.

IE..

```
NSMutableArray *htmlFileList @"blah blah blah" @"blah" @"blahsss"
NSMutableArray *htmlFileName @"blahblahblah.html" @"blah.html" @"blahsss.html"
```

my prepare for segue located in my tableviewcontroller looks like this

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"currentHtmlFile"]) {

}
DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
Guide *g = [htmlFiles objectAtIndex:path.row];

[dvc setCurrentFile:g];
```

I don't know the correct usage of UIWebview or NSURL to display it in my DetailViewController.
Some of the methods i have tried include putting the info in the

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

and others I have tried using

```
-(void)viewWillApear
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Performing the segue? Setting up the UIWebView?

Comment: @micantox Setting up the UIWebView in the DetailViewController. I have tried a couple of ways with setting up UIWebView *webView and NSURL but to no avail. I do not know the correct lanuage needed here as I have not done this before. Any other examples I find are usin XIB Files.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is:

1. In your storyboard, add a Web View object to your DetailViewController by dragging it from the Object Library (where buttons, labels, etc. are)
2. In your DetailViewController class, create an outlet for the Web View, you do this by ctrl-dragging the web view into your DetailViewController code (where you would declare properties, so in the @interface of your class) and give it a name, such as myWebView.
3. In your viewWillAppear method insert the following code:

   ```
   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:myURL];
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
   [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
   ```

   where myURL is the url string that was selected in your table view.

These 3 simple steps should solve your problems :)

Comment: this is something I have tried but got errors. Let me post my errors and see if you know what I screwed up. `[myWebview loadRequest:requestObj];`   now I get an error stating that `unkown receiver 'myWebView'; did you mean 'UIWebView'?`  and also `No known class method for selector 'loadRequest:'`

Comment: If myWebView is a an outlet property, you should access it through self.myWebView.